# Json coming as null when Json is too big in Play Framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I have UI where its sending JSON object to backend (java). JSON object sometimes its `null` when JSON is too big

```
@Transactional
public static Result save() {
    try {
        JsonNode json = request().body().asJson();

        if (json == null) {
            return ok(SEND_JSON_OBJECT);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

I am getting `null` when JSON is big

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to increase the max content length by overriding the default settings for the JSON body parser for that controller action: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaBodyParsers

From the docs:

```
// Accept only 10KB of data.
@BodyParser.Of(value = BodyParser.Text.class, maxLength = 10 * 1024)
public static Result index() {
  if(request().body().isMaxSizeExceeded()) {
    return badRequest("Too much data!");
  } else {
    return ok("Got body: " + request().body().asText()); 
  }
}
```

Comment: is there any limit to max size?